# How to let failed steps in R loops output n/a or null blank so that there won't be any row number issue with data.frame() function

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, try-catch, rvest

I'm STUCK at R looping. I want to use some scraped HTML to extract several variables. I'd love to see that failed steps within an iteration output n/a or null(blank) in that column so that the row numbers remain the same as the original one for further manipulation. However, with/without trycatch(), sometimes values repeat in the output dataset, resulting in redundant observations, and there are errors showing "arguments imply differing number of rows" (see 1st picture). I'm confused. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

```
#Bring In Libraries
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

#Create a trim function to clean white space
trim <- function( x ) {
  gsub('(^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$)', '', x)
}

extract_data <- function(x,y){
  trim(sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(x,y),'[[',2),'\n'),'[[',2)) 
}

#Find the number of dog food list webpages to scrape
home <- read_html('https://www.chewy.com/b/food-332')
number <- home %>% 
  html_nodes('.results-pagination ul li:nth-child(9) a') %>%
  html_text()
#Create a blank table
all_links <- data.frame()
#### First Grab the html for every dog food ####
for (i in 1:as.numeric(number)) {
  #Read the html of the each dog food list webpage
  url <- read_html(paste0('https://www.chewy.com/b/food_c332_p',i))
  
  #Build Container for link
  for (j in 1:41) { #The biggest [j] in the CSS selector is 41 in page 1
    tryCatch({
      #This is the link to grab info for each dog food later
      link <- url%>%
        html_nodes(paste0('article:nth-child(',j,') a')) %>%
        html_attr('href')%>% nth(1)%>%
        {paste0('https://www.chewy.com',.)}
      brand <- url %>% 
        html_nodes(paste0('article:nth-child(',j,') a section div.ga-eec__brand')) %>% 
        html_text() 
      name <- url %>% 
        html_nodes(paste0('article:nth-child(',j,') a section div.ga-eec__name')) %>% 
        html_text() %>%
        {sapply(strsplit(.,','),'[[',1)} %>%
        {gsub('^[[:alpha:]]/d ','',.)} %>%#Clean title with irregular prefix
        str_remove(brand)%>% trim() 
      links <- {data.frame(html=link, Name=name, Brand=brand)} #%>%
        #dplyr::rename(html=1)
      print(paste0('Finished page ',i,', item ',j))
      all_links <- rbind(all_links,links)
    }, error=function(e){cat(conditionMessage(e))})  
  }
}
```

[image: Repeated html]

Other times the loop skips the whole iteration where any value is failed to extract, and jump directly to the next iteration, resulting in fewer observations in the output dataset compared to the original dataset (see 2nd picture).

```
#Create a blank table
stats <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(clean_links)) { 
  tryCatch({
    link <- read_html(path[i])
    #Data to scrape for each cleaned html
    brand <- link %>%
      html_nodes('#product-subtitle a span') %>% 
      html_text()%>% trim()
    name <- link %>% 
      html_nodes('#product-title h1') %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      str_remove(brand)%>% trim() %>% 
      {gsub('^[[:alpha:]]/d ','',.)} #Clean title with irregular prefix
    price <- link %>% 
      html_nodes('.ga-eec__price') %>% 
      html_text()%>% 
      {gsub('\n','',.)}%>% trim()
    size <- link %>%
      html_nodes('.ga-eec__variant')%>%
      html_text() %>% trim() 
    value <- link %>%
      html_nodes('.cw-tabs__content--right') %>%
      html_text() %>% nth(1) %>%
      {gsub('\n[[:space:]]+', '\n', .)}
    food_form <- extract_data(value,'Food Form')
    manufacturer <- extract_data(value,'Brand') 
    life_stage <- extract_data(value,'Lifestage') 
    breed_size <- extract_data(value,'Breed')
    special_diet <- extract_data(value,'Special Diet')
    
    nutro <- link %>% html_nodes('#Nutritional-Info section.cw-tabs__content--right') %>% 
      html_text()%>% 
      {as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(.,gregexpr('[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*',.))))}
    protein <- nutro[1]
    fat <- nutro[2]
    review_content<- link %>% html_nodes('.ugc-list_stars') %>%
      html_text() %>% trim()%>% parse_number()
    review_num <- review_content[1]
    rating <- review_content[2]
    recommend <- link %>%
      html_nodes('.ugc-list__recap__recommend p:nth-child(1) span') %>% 
      html_text() %>% parse_number() %>% paste0('%')
     
    #Create a table for the data
    info <- data.frame(Food_Form = food_form, Manufacturer = manufacturer, Brand = brand, Product_Name = name, Price = price, Size = size,
                       Life_Stage = life_stage, Breed_Size = breed_size, Special_Diet = special_diet,
                       Protein = protein, Fat = fat, Review_Num = review_num,
                       Recommend_percent = recommend,
                       Rating = rating, html=path[i]
                       )
    #Bind the two datasets
    stats <- rbind(stats,info)
    print(paste0('Finished with: link',i))
    }, error=function(e){cat(conditionMessage(e))})
 }
```

[image: Different row numbers]

Comment: When collecting data in a for loop, it is almost always the right answer to use some form of apply or foreach from the foreach package. Perhaps you should look up elements in vectors/lists using a function: `some.item <- fetch.element( some.list, index )` That way you could check the length or have it return NA where it would otherwise give an index error, and you wouldn't have to repeat and check try blocks through out your loop.

Comment: Instead of we debugging your code, can you share what you want to extract from different pages? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @Sirius  Thank you for your reply. Do you mean I should remove trycatch() and then use fetch.element(). I'm not sure about the exact way to do it. Can you give one example of the 2 elements "brand" and "price"? Like what should be the some.list, do I still need to output them into a dataframe "links" and then combine it with a previously created blank data frame "all_links"? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes , Yes, Sure, and Yes. The goal is to produce a data.frame with each iteration, while still allowing each variable to possibly fail. without repeating that tedious try block (packing it in a function instead)

Comment: @RonakShah I want to extract dog food data including brand, name, food form, price, size, breed, life stage, rating, review number, recommendation percentage, protein content, fat content. I'm doing it for an R class project. I use rvest, and I don't know how to use rselenium.

Comment: @Sirius I understand what you mean, but just not sure how to and where to code correctly. Can you please kindly do an example for an element "brand" in the first code, like give an exact fetch.element() code? I'm a beginner so I get confused easily. I'd appreciate your great help!

Comment: My code answer has been sitting below for 20 minutes now. I abandoned the `fetch.element` idea and went for a `try( ... ) %>% to.NA` construct instead of repeating try/catch testing for each assignment, do it in one function that you then use where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some, not all of those statements, are at risk of throwing an error and throwing the entire row of the data.frame

I'd take away the tryCatch block. And instead identifying the statements at risk.

```r
library(bettertrace) ## good for seeing what statements actually trigger errors

## a little helper
to.NA <- function( x ) {
  if( inherits(x, "try-error") || is.null(x) ) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

## and later in your block:

##  [...]

  fat <- try( nutro[2] ) %>% to.NA

  food_form <- try( extract_data(value,'Food Form') ) %>% to.NA

  ## etc.

  
}
```

In essence I'm just running try catch with each statement, instead the entire block, and making it more livable with a helper function.

You could throw `try` in to the function as well, but its also ok to have it there on each line to better show what's actually happening.

You can then keep the code you have to add these to the data.frame, but you will now have NA's instead, which should not mess up your structure

(also notice how `to.NA` does not mess with your data when data extraction is successfull)

Comment: Thank you! There's an issue with bettertrace package, it's unavailable for the newest R Version 1.4.1103, I'm trying to find a compatible version. Plus, can I ask one more question? For piping code like:   review_content<- link %>% html_nodes('.###') %>% html_text() %>% trim()  ,should I update it like: review_content<- link %>% html_nodes('.###') %>% html_text() %>% trim() %>% try() %>% to.NA()      ?

Comment: I think you can only install the package from github: so `devtools::install_github( "robertzk/bettertrace" )` (so you need to have the devtools package installed)

Comment: Regarding chaining order - I had to try it to make sure - but it appears you can. There's always the risk that it wouldn't capture the entire chain, but appears it does! If you are comfortable you know what you are doing, go ahead!

Comment: np, pelase mark this as the accepted answer if you are happy